# How can I read a mixed type csv file without using packages with octave?

Tags: octave

I have  a mixed type csv file that looks like this:

```
name,age,score
""hans"",12,23
""thomas"",34,23
""sarah"",23,123
```

that I would like to load in octave.
How can I deal with the strings in this?
I am not allowed to use packages and so I have no idea if it is even possible to load this file. Is there a way to go through the file line by line and analyzing and splitting each line by hand?

Comment: In MATLAB you can specify file-styles, in this  case `%s,%d,%d`, to the various read functions. I'm unfamiliar with Octave, so you'd have to see whether you can specify a similar thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a delimited file with strings/numbers with Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301419/how-do-i-read-a-delimited-file-with-strings-numbers-with-octave)

Comment: thats how I ended up doing it. Although someone should edit it and that for csvs u gotta use textscan, you have to get the fid with fopen and read the first (header) line with fgtl

Comment: Who should edit what? Why do you have to use `textscan`? `textread` will skip the header when given the `"headerlines"` option.

Comment: Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61036374/1377097) prefers `csv2cell`.